# syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE)

Tags: php, html, mysql, associative-array

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

used

```
echo img src=$row['logo']>."<br />";
```

what is the correct use

I wanted to show it as a picture

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to change your code as below:

```
echo "<img src='$row[logo]' /><br />";
```

OR

```
echo "<img src='".$row[logo]."' /><br />";
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php

echo "some string {$variable['withKey']}";
```

encapsulate the variable with `{` and `}`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<img src=\"$row['logo']\" />";
```

notice the quotes around your `src` attribute which are needed for your HTML to work